# Forza 4 racing weak vs strong cars like in Forza 3

Tags: forza-motorsport-4

in Forza 3 it was possible to tune out a car to ridiculous levels of performance (like 400 hp Mazda 2 - class A) and still race against class F AI opponents in some events. It was fun as I was also able to take Dodge Ram and harass the small AI cars, wreck them, crash them and do general evil in a simulator-like game.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do this in Forza 4 anymore. Is a possibility of having 15 F-class AI cars on track and crushing them with super fast Hummer H1? As far as I have discovered, there isn't a way to race cars with lower classes, except for a handful of mixed-class events.

Should I go back to having fun in Forza 3 or is there a way to do this in Forza 4?

Answer (score 1):

Create a private online race and change the Game Setup to F class. All AI drivers now have a F class car. Then change the Game Setup and remove the class restriction, so that all classes are allowed. The AI will stay in their F class crappy cars and you can pick whatever you like. Have fun!